# Why can't I use this in (JavaScript) Worker when defining an object?

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, web-worker, prototype-programming

Coming from the Java (OOP) world, I am used to classes, inheritance and multi threading. Now for my little walkabout in the JavaScript domain, I try to utilize these paradigms and patterns where applicable. Read: use prototypes ("classes" / objects) and WebWorkers for parallel execution. However, this one case does not work ...

HTML site starting a worker:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
        worker.onmessage(event) {
            // here be fancy script
        }
        worker.postMessage("run, worker, run!"); 
        </script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Worker called by HTML ("worker.js"):

```
self.loadScripts("handler.js");
var handler = null;
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    if(!handler) {
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    handler.compute();
}
```

The Handler as called by the worker ("handler.js"):

```
function Handler() {
}

Handler.prototype = {
    compute: function() {
        this.doSomething(); // <-- ERROR! "this" points to the worker context,
                            // not to the Handler instance. So "doSomething" is
                            // undefined. However, the following line would work:
        // Handler.prototype.doSomething();
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        // More code here
    }
}
```

Is JavaScript prototyping and "inheritance" meant to work this way? Should I always use the prototype property instead of this? What if I want to access this.myProperty instead of a function?

Also: is there any reasonable way to bind this to the Handler instance in the constructor? At least the code is not cluttered with lengthy Handler.prototype references.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to [pass the context in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), otherwise `this` will reference whatever the global scope is.

Comment: Seems to me like it should work (though I'm not too familiar with WebWorkers). Are we missing any relevant code? `this` in the `compute` function should be the `handler` object it was called against.

Comment: I'd suggest you first make sure the code works outside of a web worker so you aren't missing something obvious.  Then, put it in a web worker and test there.  When you call a method on an object, `this` should be set to the object like you are expecting so there is something amiss in the code (which I don't see at the moment).

Comment: Awkward! The contrived example works ... I'll keep you posted.

Comment: The typical solution is to assign `var obj = this` before the setTimeout captured a closure and refer to `obj` in the setTimeout function instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. Indeed, the context of this works as expected. The real code used a timeout callback:

```
Handler.prototype = {
    compute: function() {
        self.setTimeout(this.doSomething, 1000); // Here the this got lost
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

It seems this from a timeout call is referencing the worker context. To solve the issue, I just wrapped the callback in an anonymous function (referencing the caller as a variable, as jfriend00 suggested):

```
Handler.prototype = {
    compute: function() {
        var caller = this;
        self.setTimeout(function() { // Wrap for great justice
            caller.doSomething();
            } , 1000);
    }, doSomething: function() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Thanks again.